# How to save time when pulling data from DB using Entity Framework Core in controller with paging?

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, paging

I am in a situation my web based application having slow performance after reading data from DB (100-200 records) before displaying on the page with paging enabled. I followed the example from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-paging

I found that when my code loops through the data from the database, processes it and adds it into a list, it takes about half second for each record, more or less, according to the execution time I output.

The example from Microsoft does:

1. Pull the data
2. Process the data depends on input for sorting, filtering
3. Page the data before return to the view to display

That sounds like it will cause performance issue when there is a large number of records in the DB as it pull everything first, then page it.

I am wondering what is the right approach to improve the performance? Also should I save the data in cache/session to save time, when the page is refreshed or previous/next page button is clicked?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Below is the key part of the Index Action in the Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    // Read all raw data from DB
    var allRequests = (from r in _context.Request).ToList();

    // Create the ViewModel object List
    List<CreateRequestViewModel> createRequestList = new List<CreateRequestViewModel>();

    foreach (Request request in allRequests)
    {
        CreateRequestViewModel createRequest = new CreateRequestViewModel();
        createRequest.RequestId = request.RequestId;
        // Some customized code to assign value to the ViewModel object's properties

        // Add the ViewModel object to the List
        createRequestList.Add(createRequest);
    }

    // Return the PaginatedList using ViewModel List created above with paging to the page.
    return View(PaginatedList<CreateRequestViewModel>.CreateAsync(createRequestList.AsQueryable(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
}

public static PaginatedList<T> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var items = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

Comment: Show model, show your loop.  There is no enough information to aim in right direction.

Comment: The example is *not* pulling data. The first two steps are just building dynamically LINQ query to be executed later.

Comment: Could this document answer your question?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Sure, I added the code sample in my Controller, hope that helps

Comment: @IvanStoev, Thanks, as most of the time the code spent on looping through the records from DB and transform to the ViewModel object, then add into a List, I guess, I need to optimize the performance there, correct? And it takes more time if there are more records in the DB.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng, Thank you, I did find this Microsoft page, but don't know which approach I should use. As the paging code sample seems reading all data first, then process it before display only the small amount of data for the current page, would the process part still be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you want pagination on the server side, you have to work with `IQueryable` created from `DbSet<>`

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    var query = _context.Request.AsQueryable();

    // apply filters to query
    ...

    var result = query.Select(r => new CreateRequestViewModel
    {
        RequestId = r.RequestId,
        // ... other fields
    });

    
    // Return the PaginatedList using ViewModel List created above with paging to the page.
    return View(PaginatedList<CreateRequestViewModel>.CreateAsync(result, page ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: Great that works. Just a quick question, on top of this logic, if I want to filter the query variable based on another database entity's data before go into PaginatedList e.g. only include the item r into the variable result when r.RequesterEmail is in another variable emailList (List of strings or can be a long string with emails like email1@abc.com,email2@abc.com) generated from _contextdb2, is it still possible? Or I need to use ToList instead of AsQueryable for variable query to get the data first, then apply my filtering logic from emailList before PaginatedList? Thank you.

Comment: It is hard to say. If DbContext is the same almost all is possibel.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it's two different DBContext. I guess I have to use ToList() to get the data first from dbcontext1 for query variable. Then filter using emailList generated from dbcontext2 before PaginatedList.

Comment: You can do filter by `Contains` then. Better to create new question if you need more details.

Comment: Yeah I did try filter by Contains, but it failed there. This is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035500/entityframeworkcore-performance-tuning-when-filter-one-dbcontext-object-using-th appreciated if you think there is any better solution. Thank you, have a good weekend.